# reCAPTCHA not tappable on zoomed out page

Tags: responsive-design, touch, recaptcha

having a strange issue with Google reCAPTCHA (v2, checkbox).

In particular, it is not clickable when the following two conditions match:

1. The browser is in a "touch device" mode;
2. The page zoom is not equal to 100% (the exact value seem to depend on the original iframe position)

Here, I've done an example: https://mityukov.github.io/re.html

Is there any way to overcome this issue?